# bi-directional communication between server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Can anybody suggest a javascript/nodejs solution for bi-directional communication between server and client. The application flow will be like this, Client sent a discovery service to a server and server will sent back a challenge to client , client should reply back to the challenge and server validates the challenge and accepts it. In some case server can directly process the request without challenge.

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Just use standard HTTP requests and responses? If there is a need for a challenge, respond with the challenge, and let the client do a second request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will help:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

Sample code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('request', /* */); // emit an event to the socket
  io.emit('broadcast', /* */); // emit an event to all connected sockets
  socket.on('reply', function(){ /* */ }); // listen to the event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest the Socket. Io which will you achieve the bi-direction communication between the client and serve.

Please look at the below link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/

Make sure you have to confiquere

Socket. Io as well as socket. Io-clientt